# Можно запретить элементу деформацию, изменение размера, при изменении разрешения окна?

Tags: css

Только не используя min max height/width, а другим путем?

Т.к у меня там с % даны все разрешения, а мин макс требуют пиксели

**UPDATE**

```
#team {
width: 100%;
height: 80%;
}

#team .cell {
height: 40%;
width: 19.5%;
float: left;
margin-left: 3%;
margin-bottom: 9%;
}
```

Дело в том, что родительский блок у меня в %. А дочерний если ставить с помощью min max в пикселях, то идет искажение/деформация по полной программе!

Выходит, что для того, чтобы исправить это, мне придется + поиграть с родительским блоком. Это как "Эффект Домино" будет

Comment: Раз требуют - дайте. А вообще, соберите пример на jsFiddle, чтобы было понятно, о чем вы вообще толкуете.

Comment: а Вам чтобы понять деформацию элемента при изменении разрешения окна нужен наглядный пример???

Comment: порой вопросы формулируются так, что без примера крайне затруднительно понять, что имеется в виду :)

Comment: К примеру, у textarea есть свойство disabled, которое запретит изменение размера поля.

Но если вы имеете ввиду любое изменение, включая изменение при помощи внешних источников таких как консоль браузера, то вам необходимо при помощи js регулярно (раз в какое-то время) проверять, не изменены ли размеры и, если они изменены, возвращать размеры необходимые. Это приведёт к "дёрганию" элемента, зато размеры всегда будут неизменны.

Однако, этот ответ вам явно не подходит. Я не поленился его написать, чтоб вы поняли, зачем нам для ответа даже элементарный пример.

Comment: Я не пойму, а в чем, если не в пикселях, вы хотите задавать минимальный размер?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**
Посмотреть **[пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/mYrRx/)**.

**html**

```
<!-- Чтобы ширина дочерних блоков, указанная в %, не менялась с изменением окна,
     у родительского блока должны быть жестко заданы ширина и высота в пикселях.
     Это обязательное условие.
     Чтобы не менять ваши стили, оборачиваем содержимое #team в еще один div: -->
<div id="content">
    <div id="team">
        <div class="cell">Team A</div>
        <div class="cell">Team B</div>
        <div class="cell">Team C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
/* Задаем фиксированную высоту и ширину для обертки */
#content {
    height: 500px; 
    width: 650px;
}
/* Ваши стили. Границы добавлены для демонстрации */
#team {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
}
#team .cell {
    border: 1px solid #f00;    
    float: left;
    height: 40%;    
    margin-left: 3%;
    margin-bottom: 9%;
    width: 19.5%;
}
```